# Quantifiers for all x,y in R

Tags: quantifiers

Can I write

$$\forall{ x, y \in{\mathbb{R}}}$$

Instead of

$$\forall{ x \in{\mathbb{R}}} \, \forall{ y \in{\mathbb{R}}}$$

Since it is much shorter and a similar notation is usually used in sets?

Comment: Better use $\forall(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS No need for that. It is well established that $\forall x,y\in A$ is just shorthand for $\forall x\in A, \forall y\in A$.

Comment: As it is established that $\forall x\in A,\ \mathcal P(A)$ is a shorthand for $\forall x,\ (x\notin A\vee \mathcal P(A))$. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. In fact it is much more usual to write $\forall x,y\in\mathbb R$ than $\forall x\in\mathbb R\,\forall y\in\mathbb R$.